# How to sort Objects by Duration time?

Tags: java

I have list of Lap models :

```
List<Lap> sortedListOfRacers = new ArrayList<>();
```

then I fill this list with different values using `Lap lap = new Lap(racer, start, end, Duration.between(start, end));`

where `start` and `end` are LocalDateTime.

I have Comparator :

```
public class TimeComparator implements Comparator<Lap> {


@Override
public int compare(Lap o1, Lap o2) {
    int digitOfReturnedValue = -2;

    Lap s1 = o1;
    Lap s2 = o2;
    if (s1.getTimeOfLap().equals(s2.getTimeOfLap())) {
        digitOfReturnedValue = 0;
    } else if (s2.getTimeOfLap().toMillis() < (s1.getTimeOfLap().toMillis())) {
        digitOfReturnedValue = 1;
    } else {
        digitOfReturnedValue = -1;
    }
    return digitOfReturnedValue;
}
```

and `Collections.sort(sortedListOfRacers, new TimeComparator());`,

It doesn't sort all values.

I suppose that I have wrong Comparator, I will be grateful for you help.

Answer (score 3):

There is no point manually extracting the milliseconds. `Duration` is already comparable.

```
@Override
public int compare(Lap o1, Lap o2) {
    return Comparator.comparing(Lap::getTimeOfLap).compare(o1, o2);
}
```

Worth noting, this renders your TimeComparator basically useless, since it can be created in almost the same number of characters

```
new TimeComparator()
Comparator.comparing(Lap::getTimeOfLap)
```

Comment: Maybe I am confused but It didn't help

Comment: Provide some sample data, the result, and why the result diverges from what you expect. E.g. "*Lap X is sorted to be last even though it was faster than Lap Y*"

Comment: I convert data from Duration to String of this Duration ( I take minutes, seconds and nanoseconds ) and when I sort It, It doesn't sort by the best times.
Then I have data in String : 
1:04.415
1:12.013
1:12.848
Should they be sorted via Duration or not?

Comment: Like I said, provide sample data. We should be able to run your code. At the moment we can't. Read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We want to help you but we can't if you don't give us the information we need in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 introduced a couple of built-in comparators to prevent the most common pitfalls. Using

```
Comparator.comparingLong(d -> d.getTimeOfLap().toMillis())
```

should do the trick in your case.